# событие change для input type=range

Tags: javascript, jquery

Событие `change` для `input type=text` срабатывает после потери фокуса, а для `type=range` оно срабатывает сразу при изменении,
как отловить момент, когда человек заканчивает двигать слайдер? `mouseover` кажется не подойдет, ибо работа с сайтом будет проходить с планшета, или Я не прав?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Описанной Вами проблемы не наблюдаю.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('input').change(function() {
    console.log('Change: ' + $(this).val())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" />
```

Пока мы двигаем слайдер (вводим текст) мы модифицируем значение input и событие не возникает. Когда мы бросили слайдер (вышли из текстового инпута) мы говорим, что изменения закончены и можно поднимать событие. Все логично.

Comment: Поменял вопрос, посмотрите теперь пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Comment: @GicO Вы своей правкой полностью изменили суть вопроса. Я откатил вопрос к первоначальному варианту. Если мой ответ решил Вашу проблему, отметьте его как правильный. Если у Вас есть еще вопрос - задайте его как новый