# jQuery сброс нажатия на ползунок

Tags: javascript, jquery

помогите решить проблему, есть некий бустрап слайдер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после каждого перемещении слайдера влево или право мне нужно обновлять страницу, я повесил обработчик клик на ползунок он срабатывает все нормально , но есть проблема если повести ползунок и немного вылезти из-за его пределы то клик уже не срабатывает и данные не обновляются к примеру так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтобы слайдер срабатывал после перемещения любого ?

```
$(document).on('click','.slider-handle',function () {
    updateSkull();
});
```

Код HTML http://prntscr.com/kad1f9

есть еще такая возможность

```
$("#coin").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    console.log(slideEvt);
});
```

но события срабатывают все время что тянется слайдер и их может быть много а мне нужно одно чтобы обновить страницу много раз нельзя так как будет постоянно обновляться страница http://prntscr.com/kad6p0

Comment: слайдер и функционал еже есть рабочий мне нужно связать функционал

Comment: а вы не думаете что обновление страницы целиком это процесс не быстрый, при плохом соединении может занимать до нескольких секунд, даже если страница мало весит

Comment: + нужно ведь ещё запоминать где-то текущее положение слайдера... Допустим в куках, а если куки отключены?

Comment: та можно запоминать но , мы запоминаем и обновляем страницу а что именно запоминать если пользователь тянет ползунок 59,60,61 как понять на каком он остановился и как поймать событие что он остановился ?

Comment: Вопрос не в том как запоминать, а в том, нафига вообще это нужно? Даже если у вас что-то получится, вы потом сами поймете, что это бред, когда при каждом сдвиге бегунка пользователю придется ждать 1-2 секунды

Comment: - Анатолий Шевелев- мне нужно чтобы пользователь сдвинул бегунки как ему нужно а мы запомнили и обновили данные , пользователь один раз установит что ему нужно , не пойму зачем обсуждать техническое решение если я прошу помощи в решении конкретной задачи

Comment: ну прикрутите вы кнопку рядом, пользователь сдвинет бегунок, нажмет на кнопку и данные обновятся 1 раз

Comment: спасибо за подсказку но нужно решении в существующих рамках

Comment: ну тогда попробуйте повесить слушатель на событие `mouseup` над бегунком

Comment: Укажите в вопросе, какой конкретно слайдер вы используете? Желательно со ссылкой на документацию и\или исходники.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолесник Все нормальные слайдеры генерируют событие `onChange`. Именно его и надо отлавливать - (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/771967/265406)